# Attach sameplerate or dmix ALSA plugin to OSS device

Tags: linux, open-source, embedded, alsa

I have an application in an embedded system that has a application which is OSS based.  Unfortunately, this application is at a fixed sample rate (8K), but I need it to be at 48K.  Furthermore, I can't change the application.

I'm researching sample rate conversion plugins, such as dmix or libsamplerate, but I don't see how to use that with OSS.

Can somebody please point me in the right direction?  Can I configure ALSA in such a way as to convert the OSS interface from 8K->48K in/out of the system?

TIA

Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is the `alsa-oss` package which provides a tool you can use to run a program and redirect it's OSS sound output into ALSA where all the normal ALSA tools are available.